# Show that $\log(1+y) \approx y- \frac {y^2}2 + \cdots$ without Taylor Series

Tags: calculus, logarithms

> For small $y$, prove that $\log(1+y)\approx y -\frac {y^2}2 + \cdots $

I have no idea to solve it.

Comment: Did you study Taylor series?

Comment: Ever heard of series?

Comment: Ummm its Taylor series but I won't study it yet

Comment: What definitions of logarithms do you know? Some of these definitions may be useful in solving this problem (if you can't use Taylor series or integration)

Comment: Ik some definition of logarithms but can u specify which definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure you know [the geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series)

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-y)^n=1-y+y^2-y^3+\ldots=\frac{1}{1+y},\qquad |y|<1\tag{1}$$

Now integrate both sides of $(1)$, and the result follows. For small $y$, the higher power terms become negligible.

Comment: Sir,I can use binomial theorem for rational index to get$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-y)^n=1-y+y^2-y^3+\ldots=\frac{1}{1+y}$$ but if using geometric series formula I found $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-y)^n=1-y+y^2-y^3+\ldots$$=(1+y) instead of$\frac{1}{1+y}$ can u help me to get correct answer

Comment: @SathasivamK look at the formula for a geometric sum again, it's $\frac{a}{1 - r}$ where $a$ is the first term and $r$ is the common ratio. (for infinite sums) so in this case $a=1, r=-y$ so the sum is $\frac{1}{1-(-y)} = \frac{1}{1 +y}$.

Comment: Oh sorry I won't see the n=$\infty $ in this series

Comment: Your answer is very help ful @Zain Patel

Answer (score 3):

One approach directly based on a definition of $\log x$ is as follows. We use the following definition of $\log x$ $$\log x = \lim_{n \to \infty}n(x^{1/n} - 1)$$ Replacing $x$ by $(1 + x)$ and for $|x| < 1$ using binomial theorem we get
\begin{align}
\log (1 + x) &= \lim_{n \to \infty}n((1 + x)^{1/n} - 1)\notag\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty}n\left(\frac{x}{1!}\frac{1}{n} - \frac{x^{2}}{2!}\frac{1}{n}\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right) + \frac{x^{3}}{3!}\frac{1}{n}\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)\left(2 - \frac{1}{n}\right) + \cdots\right) \notag\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty}\left(x - \frac{x^{2}}{2!}\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right) + \frac{x^{3}}{3!}\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)\left(2 - \frac{1}{n}\right) + \cdots\right)\notag\\
&= x - \frac{x^{2}}{2} + \frac{x^{3}}{3} - \cdots\notag
\end{align}
The last step where I took limit of an infinite series term by term requires some justification which might not be suitable at your stage of learning (as guessed from the content of question and comments to it). Moreover since you need only an approximation it is better to just take the terms till $x^{2}$ in the binomial expansion and then take limit.

Another approach is available [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1869524/72031).

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to assume that $\ln (1+y) \approx a + by + cy^2$ and then differentiate twice and use $y=0$ to get $\ln (1+y) \approx y - \frac{y^2}{2}$.

Comment: That's actually a good approach, if Taylor series or integration are not allowed. +1

Comment: This is actually a non-rigorous and incorrect approach. When $f(x) \approx g(x)$ then you mean that $f(x) = g(x) + R(x)$ where $R(x)$ is an error term which can be made small depending on values of $x$. Now differentiating this we get $f'(x) = g'(x) + R'(x)$. Now $R(x)$ being small does not mean $R'(x)$ is small and hence $f'(x)$ is not necessarily approximately equal to $g'(x)$. It is better to use integration rather than differentiation. If $R(x)$ is small its integral is also going to be small. Start with $(1 + x)^{-1} \approx 1 - x$ and integrate.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh, I meant the polynomial approximation approach in general, I did not consider the possible mistakes, thank you for correcting

Answer (score 2):

For  any $y\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $|y|<1$ we have:
$$ \log(1+y) = \int_{0}^{y}\frac{dx}{1+x} \tag{1}$$
but if $|x|<1$ we also have:
$$ \frac{1}{1+x} = 1-x+\frac{x^2}{1+x}\tag{2} $$
and:
$$ \log(1+y) = \color{red}{y-\frac{y^2}{2}}+\color{blue}{\int_{0}^{y}\frac{x^2}{1+x}\,dx} \tag{3}$$
where, by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
$$\left|\color{blue}{\int_{0}^{y}\frac{x^2}{1+x}\,dx}\right|^2 \leq \int_{0}^{y}\frac{dx}{(1+x)^2}\int_{0}^{y}x^4\,dx = \frac{y^6}{5(1+y)^2}.\tag{4} $$

Truth to be told, $(3)$ is just an instance of Taylor's formula with  integral remainder:
$$ \forall |y|<1,\qquad \log(1+y)=\color{red}{\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^k}{k}\,y^k}+\color{blue}{(-1)^{n+1}\int_{0}^{y}\frac{x^{n+1}}{x+1}\,dx}.\tag{5} $$

Comment: @FelixMarin: thank you, typo fixed.