# Dubious proof of logarithmic series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

While [answering this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1869492/72031) I got reminded of a proof for the logarithmic series $$\log(1 + x) = x - \frac{x^{2}}{2} + \frac{x^{3}}{3} - \cdots + (-1)^{n - 1}\frac{x^{n}}{n} + \cdots\tag{1}$$ which I read long ago in many Indian textbooks.

The proof makes use of the two famous series: the exponential series and the binomial series given below
\begin{align}
\exp(x) &= 1 + x + \frac{x^{2}}{2!} + \cdots + \frac{x^{n}}{n!} + \cdots\text{ for all real }x\tag{2}\\
(1 + x)^{a} &= 1 + ax + \frac{a(a - 1)}{2!}x^{2} + \cdots + \binom{a}{n}x^{n} + \cdots\text{ for all real }a, x\text{ with }|x| < 1\tag{3}
\end{align}
Using $(2)$ we can write $$(1 + x)^{a} = \exp(a\log(1 + x)) = 1 + a\log(1 + x) + \frac{a^{2}}{2!}(\log(1 + x))^{2} + \cdots\tag{4}$$ and then equating the coefficient of $a$ in the series $(3)$ and $(4)$ we get $$\log(1 + x) = x - \frac{x^{2}}{2} + \frac{x^{3}}{3} - \cdots + (-1)^{n - 1}\frac{x^{n}}{n} + \cdots$$ But I never believed this proof to be true. In fact it does not deal with any convergence issues related to the resulting series. At best it can be said to be a technique for manipulating *formal* power series.

> Do we have any general theorem behind the working of this method? To add some symbolism let $f(x, a)$ be a function which can be expanded as a power series in $x$ as $$f(x, a) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}f_{n}(a)x^{n}\tag{5}$$ and also as a power series in $a$ as $$f(x, a) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}g_{n}(x)a^{n}\tag{6}$$ for certain range of values of $a, x$ in which both the above expansions hold true. Under what conditions (perhaps imposed on $f_{n}(a), g_{n}(x)$) can we equate coefficients of $a^{n}$ in both $(5)$ and $(6)$ and get results which are true for the values of $x$ under which both $(5)$ and $(6)$ hold?

The only result about equating coefficients of power series which I am aware of is the following:

*If $$\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n} = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} b_{n}x^{n}$$ for all values of $x \in (-R, R)$ then $a_{n} = b_{n}$ for all $n$.*

The above ensures uniqueness of power series of a function.